# Does using an ORM, like Ebean, make encapsulation impossible? Is it worth caring?

Tags: java, orm, encapsulation

I'm a computer science student at a university working on an independent study.  As I'm just learning, I'm trying to make sure I get the basics down, to develop good habits for the future.

Recently I had taken to enforcing encapsulation as much as possible.  For example, using `Collections.unmodifiableList()` to return unmodifiable lists.  For my study I'm using Ebean for my database model and have found that, 1) every class must have a public no arg constructor and 2) public getters and setters for every field.  I understand that the way Ebean works, using reflection, requires this, it just makes me wonder: Is encapsulation that important?

Comment: For entity classes normally no, but we need to follow the orm framework rules. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ebean does not require any public constructors/getters/setters. The constructor can be private and you can make Ebean use fields directly.

See chapter 14 of the [user guide](http://www.avaje.org/doc/ebean-userguide.pdf).

Both Hibernate and myBatis(though not an ORM) can handle private constructors/fields, too.